# Spaces between images @Html.Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two images like so. (granted that the code is indented)

```
@Html.Image("/Images/icons/arrow-up.gif", "up")
@Html.Image("/Images/icons/arrow-down.gif", "up")
```

The images have a space between them.

I instead have to write as a sigle line to avoid a gap between the images, which i find not very readable:

```
@Html.Image("/Images/icons/arrow-up.gif", "up")@Html.Image("/Images/icons/arrow-down.gif", "up")
```

How can I fix this? thanks

**Additional:** Here are the two cases as printscreens

**Case 1:**

[image]

[image]

**Case 2:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the best solution seems to be this.

```
@{
    @Html.Image("/Id/Images/icons/arrow-up.gif", "up")  
    @Html.Image("/Id/Images/icons/arrow-down.gif", "up")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this?

This doesn't require any fixing. No browser cares whether there's a space or not between your HTML tags. You could of course write a custom helper that will output the two images at once:

```
@Html.MyImages("/Images/icons/arrow-up.gif", "/Images/icons/arrow-down.gif")
```

but IMHO that would be useless work.

Maybe the *space* you are talking about comes from some CSS rule on the containing element? Maybe setting a 0 padding and margin would remove it?

Comment: I have added some screenshots.

Comment: Most browsers *do* automatically add a small gap between elements if a linebreak or other whitespace is encountered. Anchor tags and buttons, for example, do this.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly and i am not saying you should use this solution but try:

```
ul#Test li {float:left;list-style-type:none;}
ul#Test li img {border:none; padding:0; margin:0}
```

Then with some css:

```
<ul id="Test">
    <li>@Html.Image("/Images/icons/arrow-up.gif", "up")</li>
    <li>@Html.Image("/Images/icons/arrow-down.gif", "up")</li>
</ul>
```